# Textarea autocomplete by sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Does anybody knows a javascript or jquery plugin that autocompletes a paragraph in textarea but not in a datalist way. I want a plugin that whenever I type a word it suggest a paragraph that is highlighted inside the textarea and the suggested paragraph will only implemented if I press enter or just keep suggesting whenever I type a word that matched the paragraph I saved in my database. I tried to search for that plugin but I always ended up in a plugin that only suggest 1 word and I have to choose in datalist option. A great example of it is in the browser address bar, example I type `go` it will suggest `google.com` but the `ogle.com` is highlighted and the `go`(which I typed was not highlighted) and whenever I type for the next letter it removes the highlight for the letter I just typed.

Comment: No, why should someone build such a plugin? What's the use case?

Comment: I also wonder why the `address bar` of browser have that kind of autocomplete :). Since autocomplete exist and since `browser address bar` can do this kind of auto completion, I assume that "MAYBE" someone out there build/convert this kind of autocomplete in a form of `jquery/javascript` plugin to help others who wants to have that kind of auto completion. I hope I answer your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a plugin which do what I want but suggestion stops when user hit `space`. I hope I can find a plugin that will continue suggesting `paragraph` even I press `space`. http://imankulov.github.io/asuggest/index.html

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: No sir. Im stuck in here